# Saving array of children of a Mongoose Schema and then adding returned IDs to parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

i'm trying to loop over an array of objects, saving them to MongoDB and then add the returned ObjectIds to a parent Schema which then is also saved. I'm at a loss here.

Everything gets saved correctly but the *`Recipe` (parent) apparently is saved before I get the returned ObjectIds of the `Tag`s (children)*. I feel like I've used the `async` and `await` keywords a bit to often.

Can someone help? Code simplified, but I can post more if needed.

Parent Schema:

```js
const recipe = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        ingredients: [
            {
                type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
                ref: "Ingredient",
            },
        ],
    }
);
```

Child Schema:

```js
const ingredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value:  String,
    label: String,
});
```

Payload:

```json
{
    name: "Rezept",
    ingredients: [
        {
            label: "zutat",
            value: "Zutat",
        },
        {
            label: "schokolade",
            value: "Schokolade",
        },
    ],
};
```

My router:

```js
recipesRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;
    const saveIngredients = async () => {
        let ingredientIDs = [];
        body.ingredients.map(async (ingredient) => {
            const i = new Ingredient({
                value: ingredient.value,
                label: ingredient.label,
            });

            const savedIngredient = await i.save();
            ingredientIDs.push(savedIngredient._id);
        });
        return ingredientIDs;
    };    

    const recipe = new Recipe({
        name: body.name,        
        ingredients: (await saveIngredients()) || [],
       
    });
    const savedRecipe = await recipe.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedRecipe);
});
```

Returned recipe:

```js
savedRecipe: {
    name: 'asd',
    ingredients: [],
    _id: new ObjectId("62782b45a431e6efb7b8b1a7"),
}
```

As I said, both ingredients individually and the recipe is saved to the MongoDB after this but not the ingredient IDs in the recipe. The returned recipe has an empty array in `ingredients`. I guess the recipe is saved too soon before MongoDB can return ObjectIds for the ingredients.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it smh. Turns out `async` in a `.map` or `.foreach` doesn't go well. I turned it  into a simple `for loop`. It's still bloated/lot of steps imo but it works!

```js
recipesRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { body } = req;

    const saveIngredients = async () => {
        let ingredientIDs = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < body.ingredients.length; i++) {
            const el = body.ingredients[i];
            const ing = new Ingredient({
                value: el.value,
                label: el.label,
            });
            const savedIngredient = await ing.save();
            ingredientIDs.push(savedIngredient._id);
        }
        return ingredientIDs;
    };

    const ingredientIDs = await saveIngredients();

    const recipe = new Recipe({
        name: body.name,
        ingredients: ingredientIDs,
    });

    const savedRecipe = await recipe.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedRecipe);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your post method is an async, so everything inside it is wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.

Do you really need to make your `saveIngredients` as an async? IMHO, it's better to let the `saveIngredients` not be in another async.

And then we can remove the empty list, and just wait for the saveIngredients() finish first.

```
 const recipe = new Recipe({
        name: body.name,        
        ingredients: await saveIngredients(),      
 });
```

Your guess is correct, the Recipe was saved first because all the conditions are fulfilled because it doesn't need to wait for the saveIngredients since you provided a `[]` as the default value. And your saveIngredients is run in parallel.

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long. I omitted the async and the empty array you mentioned (which makes sense of course because saveIngredients returns an empty array already) but I get the same results. 

I think maybe my `body.ingredients.map` in combination with `async` is wrong somehow?